# Variable within Zenity within `sh -c` ignored

Tags: bash, variables, zenity

The script below should open an entry box whose initial entry-text is the value of `$filename`, but the zenity section in the third line ignores that variable and I end up with no entry-text.

By the way, if I just replace `filename` by `whoami`, my username will appear as expected. I'm not able to get a result using my own variables, though. That's the problem.

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="duck"
sh -c 'chromium-browser "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%5C$(zenity --entry --text "I am feeling ducky" --entry-text $(filename))"'
```

And if I removed the `sh -c` stuff, to end up with the code below, my variable would work with zenity.

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="duck"
zenity --entry --text "I am feeling ducky" --entry-text $filename
```

Any clues as to why? I tried playing with different combination of quotes but my efforts were futile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation `$(filename)` runs a command 'filename'.

To expand a variable, use `${filename}`.

Note, too, that unless `$filename` is an exported variable, the sub-shell (the one that runs the `-c` option) will not see the value of the variable (because of the single quotes).

To fix that, you'd have to use double quotes - rather carefully:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="duck"
sh -c "chromium-browser \"https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%5C$(zenity --entry --text \"I am feeling ducky\" --entry-text ${filename})\""
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. It's absolutely perfect.